# How to pass a user id from an intranet to another site securely

Tags: security, authentication, cross-domain

My customer has an intranet portal and wants to have a button in it such that when clicking on it it would open my web site and login the user that was in the customer intranet automatically into my site.

The user, on both the intranet and my site, have the same user ID (the user ID is basically the email).

We do have IP authentication in place, so my site already knows the IP from where the intranet site is coming from, so that it authorizes it. Unauthorized IPs are redirected to kick them out.

How can my customer pass the user ID (aka the email in my case) from his Intranet to my web site, in such a way that it is secure?

Here are my concerns about being secure:
A) is the user ID is passed as a parameter to my web site (for example as part of the query string in the url or as a hidden input field in a form in a POST call), then there is the danger of anyone in that intranet altering this user ID by anyone else's user ID and entering as them. For example, if I am joe@abc.com, then joe@abc.com would be passed somehow from the intranet to the site as a parameter. I could easily make a change from joe@abc.com to dave@abc.com which would then log me in the site as dave@abc.com.

B) let's say that the user ID is then encrypted. So, now joe@abc.com becomes something like AAABBB000111. If I share this encrypted value with anyone, then this person could use the encrypted value and login as me. Of course I would have to share this encrypted value with him.

So, do you think that there is a good and elegant way to accomplish passing the user ID from the intranet to the external site in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

Query string can easily be used to pass this information over but if its secure i would not do that. You can pass it in a cookie which would be very easy again, If that isn't an option because the data is sensitive, you could look into [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store the data temporarily between pages.

Sending it to the server sounds the best bet log them in save there session in a cookie and then redirect them.